# How to create nested radio and input fields and a span field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I was trying to create the following form in my html

[image]

The following is my html:

```
<td>
                        <div class="input-group" ng-cloak>
                            <table class="row col-md-4">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">

                                        Select either one of the option</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <tr><input type="radio" value="A"></tr>
                                        <tr><input type="radio" value="B"></tr>
                                        <tr><input type="radio" value="C"></tr>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                            </div>
```

But as you know from this point I don't know how to continue. When I add multiple tr inside the second td, I thought it will work, but didn't. How can I make the form look in that way? Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use `<fieldset>`, `<legend>`, and `<label>` along with your input elements rather than using a table layout for this.

`<legend>` would be the element with the text "Select either one..."

`<label>` would surround your `<input>`

I will work up an example for you in a moment.

```css
body {
  margin: 2em;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-row {
  margin: 2ex 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.form-row label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}
[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 10em);
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: .5ex .25em;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
legend {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
legend span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
fieldset label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 1ex .2em 1ex 10.2em;
  padding: 1ex 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
fieldset label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  z-index: -1;
}
[type="radio"] {
  margin: 0 25px 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><span>Select either one of the options</span></legend>
    <label for="catA"><input type="radio" name="cat" id="catA" />Cat A</label>
    <label for="catB"><input type="radio" name="cat" id="catB" />Cat B</label>
    <label for="catC"><input type="radio" name="cat" id="catC" />Cat C</label>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label><input type="text" name="first-name" id="firstName" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="last-name" id="lastName" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That will be great haltersweb! Coz All these are bit new to me.

Comment: @vellattukudy I have posted the code example.  This example doesn't use table layout.  It leverages well-formed form markup with css to create the layout.  I have added two other fields below to show just what well-formed markup paired with css can do.

Comment: `fieldset` should always be used for radio or check-box clusters.  Its first child must always be `legend` which holds the question that you want them to answer with their radio selection.

Comment: `label` should always be paired with `input` and `label`'s for attribute needs to match its `input`'s id attribute.  You should never have an orphan `input` or an orphan `label`.  You can nest `input`s inside of `label`s.  I like to do that with radio buttons and checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't put a tr inside a td.  If you want to do that you need to create a table within the td.  You should read up on html tables a bit more.

The simplest way that you could do this to use rowspan which will let you merge multiple rows (as opposed to colspan which lets you merge columns on a row).

See html below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" rowspan="3">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Select either one of the option</span>
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="A"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" value="B" title="Option B"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" value="C"/></td></tr>
</table>
```